# Pseudo-algorithm for most equals group size

Tags: statistics, algorithms

Let's say I don't know how many (let's says person) will be present. I know I want to divise all those persons in group of 15. What king of algorithm could I use to create groups of person (the most evenly possible) if the number of persons present is not a multiple of 15 ?

For example, if there is 32 persons, I could do :

- 15 15 2
- 8 8 8 8
- 11 11 10

In this case, 11 11 10 is the best way to do it (Most evenly possible and the nearest possible of my 15 persons set at the beginning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that may work for you:

Let $N$ be the number of objects, and $n$ the number of groups.

1) Is $N$ divisible by $n$? If so, the number of people in each group is $\frac{N}{n}$.

2) If not, then take $\frac{N}{n}$ rounded down to the nearest integer, call this $r$.

3) $r$ is the size of the first group. Now you have $N - r$ remaining objects to be split into $n - 1$ groups.

4) Repeat this process until the number of objects left is divisible by the number of remaining groups.

Here is some code in R that accomplishes this:

```
groupSize <- function(N, n_groups, groups = c()) {
 # check if N and n_groups are reasonable
 if (N <= 0 || n_groups <= 0 || N %% 1 != 0 || n_groups %% 1 != 0 || 
       n_groups > N) {
   return(0)
 }
 if (N %% n_groups == 0) {
   size = N / n_groups
   groups = c(groups, rep(size, n_groups))
   return(groups)
 } else { # recursive step
   currentSize = N %/% n_groups
   remaining_n_groups = n_groups - 1
   remainingN = N - currentSize
   return(groupSize(remainingN, remaining_n_groups, c(groups, currentSize)))
  }
}
```

And here is the same code in Java:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getGroups(final int N, 
        final int n_groups, ArrayList<Integer> groups) {    
    // Check validity of parameters
    if (N <= 0 || n_groups <= 0 || 
            N % 1 != 0 || 
            n_groups % 1 != 0 || 
            n_groups > N) {
        System.out.println("Invalid parameters "
                + "for group size or population size");
        System.exit(0);
    }   
    if (N % n_groups == 0) { // Base case
        int size = N / n_groups;
        for (int i = 0; i < n_groups; i++)
            groups.add(size);
        return groups;
    } else { // Recursive step
        int currentSize = N / n_groups;
        int remaining_n_groups = n_groups - 1;
        int remainingN = N - currentSize;
        groups.add(currentSize);
        return getGroups(remainingN, remaining_n_groups, groups);
    }
}
```